# com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I’m getting this gradle build failure and couldn’t find any info in the documentation about it.
Found several answers asking to set an exclude in the packagingOptions{}
None of them helped(got another weird error)
Can anyone please explain what causing this error, and provide a step by step investigation/solution to overcome it?

Comment: After changing the ` packagingOptions{}` as mentioned in the answers you watched and `clean` and `rebuild` the project

Comment: Yes, even invalidated cache..

Comment: I too am experiencing this, trying to add hivemq's mqtt client library to my project

Answer (score 2):

modify app/build.gradle.

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }       
}
```

Comment: As i mentioned before.. i already tried this solution - it doesn’t work.